# Rails, Capistrano, bitbucket, permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitbucket, capistrano, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a rails application on Digital Ocean with Capistrano and I have hard times.  I get this

```
00:00 git:check
  01 git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:paaggeli/mutetale.git HEAD
  01 Permission denied (publickey).
  01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  01
  01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  01 and the repository exists.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 
46.101.112.45: Exception while executing on host 46.101.112.45: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 46.101.112.45: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Tasks: TOP => deploy:initial
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host 46.101.112.45: Exception while executing on host 46.101.112.45: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

capistrano.log file

```
 DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-mutetale-production-ubuntu.sh 0.0%

 INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-mutetale-production-ubuntu.sh 100.0%

 INFO [1baad1b1] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-mutetale-production-ubuntu.sh on 46.101.112.45

 DEBUG [1baad1b1] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.4.1" ; /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-mutetale-production-ubuntu.sh )

 INFO [1baad1b1] Finished in 0.156 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 INFO [2cd1c0fa] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:paaggeli/mutetale.git HEAD on 46.101.112.45

 DEBUG [2cd1c0fa] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.4.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-mutetale-production-ubuntu.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:paaggeli/mutetale.git HEAD )

 DEBUG [2cd1c0fa]       Permission denied (publickey).

 DEBUG [2cd1c0fa]       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.



Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.
```

Running `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` on the server returns:

logged in as paaggeli.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

Please help me

Comment: Got the same error today. But at '00:21 bundler:install' this point it got aborted. pretty much same error log.

Comment: Adding swap memory solved my problem. If possible try to upgrade your server

Comment: Thank you for your response @AkashPinnaka but still I have the same error

Answer (score 1):

Check your git access and ensure that the user your capistrano is using to clone the repo has read access.

1. Run the ssh-keygen procedure on your server.
2. In the top right corner of any GitHub page, click your profile photo.
3. On your profile page, click the Repositories tab, then click the name of your repository.
4. Settings tabIn your repository's right sidebar, click Settings.
5. In the sidebar, click Deploy Keys.
6. Click Add deploy key. Paste your public key in and submit.

https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#setup-2

Comment: How Can I Do That?

Comment: Updated the answer with instructions for how to add a deploy key

Comment: I use bitbucket and I added the public key. Still get the same error.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: did you generate the pulic key as the same ssh user that capistrano is using?
does that ssh user have write permissions to the file location?